# Some images only appear in simulator in Actions on Google App and not o real devices

Tags: image, actions-on-google

I have put some images in basic cards and in lists in Actions on google app.The problem is some of those images only appear in simulator and not on the real device.

I have tried resizing and scaling the image to those which are showing but that doesn't make any change.Some of those images which are of high quality than others appear on the real device.I don't know why this is happening.I have tested on 2 real devices both of them have the same problem.Can someone please help me?

Comment: Can you provide the URLs or examples for the images you're trying to use?

Answer (score 0):

Are you on the google 'Spark' plan.
If so you cannot access images referenced outside of google storage.
You need a paid plan to access non google url's.
I have some sample projects and my images live in 
https://console.firebase.google.com/project/`<Your Project ID`>/storage/`<Your Project ID`>.appspot.com/files
The images stored in this location are rendered with no issue.
Regards
Roy

Comment: I don't think this is true, as the platform is the one loading the image and not your project.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for providing your help,I actually found out the answer.Some of my urls contained whitespace which was handled by simulator but not the phones.So I changed the urls and now it works.